# Creating Contour Lines in QGIS 3.16 with a distance of 0,10 m

Tags: qgis, line, elevation, contour, terrain

I would like to create Isohypses (Shape) ("Create contour lines") with a distance of 0,10m in a Digital Terrain Model (Shape File).
While processing the command, there are some errors poping up:

```
ERROR 1: Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294967228 + 136.
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
```

Creating Isohypses with a distance of 0,5m to each other worked out pretty good, I guess, with a distance of 0,1m there are just too many :((

Also, some of the countour line haven't been created as well. Does somebody might know a reason for this problem and how to solve it as well?

Comment: Please provide spatial and height resolution, as well as the extent of your source data. In addition your exact conversion settings would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the result into shapefile but shapefile format has a maximum size of 4 GB https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html?#size-issues (by the original specification by ESRI even lower, 2 GB). Write the result into another format, like GeoPackage, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with either 1- very detailed elevation model or 2- very large data or 3- combined. So either your RAM or HDD is creating a barrier.

To fix it you should either 1- Command for a coarser contour, or 2- Resample the DEM to get a coarser DEM, or 3- Split up your project into smaller parts, or 4- something you see fit regarding this information. Good luck.